# NGINX load balancer and deployments

Tags: nginx

My website depends on server affinity. My setup has 2 nodes (A and B) serving client request.

Just before a deployment I want the NGINX load balancer to stop sending new requests to node B but all request that already have an affinity to node B be should be send to node B.

Is this possible with NGINX?

Answer (score 1):

Like @mikhailov told me in the comments, current requests will be finished, although the server is removed from the configuration.
So here is the tactics:

- Remove the server (which will be under deployment) from the configuration
- Reload the nginx configuration

When the deployment has finished:

- Add the server to the configuration again
- Reload the nginx configuration

Comment: Built-in *ip_hash* provides session persistence http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_with_ip_hash

Comment: Than Christopher for your response. Users with an active session on serverB need to finish with their transaction before I can remove it from the load balancer thus the need to redirect all new request to server A. I will try the 1st option.

Comment: Tell us, if it worked as wished, then! @mikhailov: Yes, but in this case he does not want to share the sessions with all servers, but let all users finish their requests first before disabling serverB.

But nevertheless I think to have shared sessions is always a great thing.

Comment: A transaction within same request/response cycle will be finished by same upstream. In case of failure request redirects to another upstream without any issue. Nginx works hard to avoid failed responses, see the proof link: http://youtu.be/yQvcHy_tPjI

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what sticky does, but what he wants is that current requests will be finished and from now on new requests to serverB should be automatically be redirected to the other available servers.
ServerB will be online the whole time - and be capable to serve requests. But for security reasons he does not want any user to be directed to this server.

Comment: @ChristopherMäuer this can be done by updating configuration (exclude ServerB for awhile) and send HUP signal to load new configuration. Current requests will be finished gracefully.

Comment: Okay, I was not sure about that.

Comment: An Nginx configuration reload is very cheap and can be performed hundred times a day. To ease it commercial Nginx+ for instance has REST interface: https://www.nginx.com/products/on-the-fly-reconfiguration/ Nevertheless open source edition works really well with on-fly config update but manual nginx.conf change and send HUP signal to master process.

Comment: Let me copy-paste what happens once you exclude server (or change its weight) from the list from orig docs: "...requests pinned to that server by session persistence continue, but new connections are throttled back" Keep in mind that Nginx controlled by Unix signals very well: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control

Answer (score 0):

You can use `server "someserverip" down;` 
This is how we do it and it works great! It allows current requests to finish and then all new requests to go other servers. Then you deploy to that server and remove "down".